# Dynamical Drop Down menu inside React-table,

Tags: reactjs

I have a React Table, one cell having drop down menu, When I change one value, all cell value rendering updating at a time, This is my drop down menu,Please help me any one know, It will be help me lot

```
this.state.status: ['delivery', 'cancel', 'pending']
 columns.push({
      Header: <b>Status</b>,
      id: `Status`,
      accessor: (str) => 'view',
      Cell: (row) => (
        <div>
          <select
            name="status"
            value={this.state.value}
            onChange={(e) => {
              this.updatedData(e, myData[row.index].id);
            }}
          >
             <option>default</option>
             <option value="deliver">deliver</option>
            <option value="cancel">cancel</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      ),
    });
```

Comment: Can you add some more code?

Comment: I add some extra code , Please help me, Its is possible

Comment: suggestion: You can format your code and then post it here.

Comment: I add code, in Proper Format